# Pythonic path splitting. Style, and best practice

Tags: python, path, operating-system, py2exe, ntfs

I have a working module, I am trying to put toghet a unified yaml file at the ROOT directory, for all sub modules to use.

I have a sub module that is 3 levels deep, and the configs.yaml is at the root.

right now I am accessing the root directory by hardcoding `os.path.split()` lines for as many levels as necessay, and I was wondering if there is a more pythonic, or a better more robust way of pointing to directory top.

I am on windows. Python 3.4, using py2exe for building.

The folder structure is as follows .

- dps_tools

  - nydps

    - edit

      - db

        - session.py
  - winsrv64

    - editservice.py

and more

### session.py segment

```
 if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
    current_directory =  os.path.split(sys.executable)[0]
else:
   current_directory = os.path.split(os.path.split(os.path.split(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.abspath("__file__")))[0])[0])[0]
```

### editservice.py

```
if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
    basis = sys.executable
else:
    basis = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("__file__"))

current_directory = os.path.split(basis)[0]
```

Is there a more consistent approach? Or perhaps a oneline pythonic way to access directory top? (even though I am on windows and directory top is not c:)

Comment: Why don't you make the directory an argument, then pass it in from the appropriate place?

Comment: Can I supply an argument to py2exe during build time? I have never tried

Comment: I will also be building this an as msi eventually, I had originally approached it as a programmatic decision, let me see if I can pass the argument around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that `os.path.dirname(filepath)` is equivalent to `os.path.split(filepath)[0]`.

But if you need to go several levels up, I'd use `os.path.normpath(os.path.join(filepath, '..', '..', '..'))`. IMHO it's more readable.

EDIT: `ntpath`'s `normpath` will also replace `/` with `\\` in the input path, so the line above can be re-written to `os.path.normpath(os.path.join(filepath, '../../..'))`, and it's be portable.